# How to concatenate video files from different sub directories using ffmpeg in win10 command prompt?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, ffmpeg, concatenation

How can I merge 1200 small mp4 files scattered in 60 subfolder,  into one big file?

My IP Camera records and stores videos in 3 second video files.
An hour long recording is stored into 60 subfolders (one for each minute). And in each of those subfolder are 20 mp4 files. (one mp4 is 3 seconds)

I found a way of doing it by having to copy each and every one of those small mp4 files into one main folder. Then use command prompt:

```
(for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt
```

to make a list file

then run:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i mylist.txt -c:v copy output2.mp4
```

And this gets the job done. But is there any graceful way of doing it without having to copy paste all of the video files?

Comment: I recommend you re-focus this question to be about cmd/powershell/batch-file. Otherwise users will think you're asking a question mostly about ffmpeg, but you already got the ffmpeg part done. ffmpeg has no such feature, so this issue will have to be dealt with via cmd/powershell/batch-file.

Answer (score 2):

With...

```
DIR *.mp4 /B /S
```

...you should get a list of all mp4-files in the current- and sub-directories.
It defaults to alphabetic filename sorting. Please consult `DIR /?` for other sorting options.

For your `ffmpeg` concat-list that would be:

```
(FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('DIR *.mp4 /B /S') DO @ECHO file '%A') > mylist.txt
```

*(`"delims="` to preserve spaces in filenames)*

Comment: whoever you are you have given me the answer that i have been looking for for several days now. I've google searched this high and low and ended up having to post this question here in stackoverflow. And lo and behold you answered my question. Very very very very much appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @raymerium You're welcome. Please have a look at ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).